# Touchpad not working on linux live USB

Tags: linux, live-usb, touchpad

A couple days ago the track pad stopped working when in Linux but works perfectly fine when in Windows.

I have tried re-flashing the USB and even tried installing different flavors of Linux to no avail.

I am not aware of any keyboard toggles for the touchpad on my particular laptop model; even so, I have tried all <kbd>fn</kbd> keys.

Sync client shows `TouchpadOff=1` but doing `synclient touchpadOff=0` makes no difference either.

Comment: Your live systems are most likely missing the driver

Comment: What laptop make and model you have?

Comment: Its the HP ENVY m6-k100 TS
and i don't think its a driver problem as this same live usb has worked on this laptop previously.
Even so, i have tried installing Synaptics drivers but that didnt work.